# PHP MongoDB Collection Size

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using the PHP MongoDB Library v1.6 and I want to be able to get the size of a specific collection. I have looked at the documentation of the [library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) and didn't see anything that would return the size. Is this possible with this library? If so could someone provide some insight on how to achieve this.

This is how I would do it from the mongo shell:

```
db.collection.dataSize()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregations with the [$collStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/collStats/) stage you can get the collection size.

Example:

```
$pipeline = [
    [
        '$collStats' => [
            'storageStats' =>
                ['scale' => 1024]
        ]
    ]
];
$storageStats = $collection->aggregate($pipeline)->toArray();
var_dump($storageStats);
```